# Is it possible to request hand inspection of photographic film in Indian airports?

Tags: air-travel, india, airport-security, photography

Per [What is the best way to carry photographic film when travelling?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61089/what-is-the-best-way-to-carry-photographic-film-when-travelling), when traveling with photographic film, it's best to pack it in hand luggage and request hand inspection of undeveloped film.

In the United States, there's an explicit TSA rule that allows you to request hand inspection of undeveloped film, and in all cases, the security officers will respect that. However, from what I've read online, security checkpoints in some countries often insist that one put undeveloped film through the scanners. (While this often results in not much visible effect for lower-speed films, it can be a problem if it's scanned multiple times, especially when transiting through different countries, and higher-speed films shouldn't be scanned at all.)

I've searched online, but I've not been able to find any information on the security rules for India, unlike the U.S. TSA which fully documents its rules online.

Is it possible or easy to request that photographic film be hand inspected at airport security checkpoints in India? Will Indian security officers usually honor the request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bureau of Civil Aviation Security](http://www.bcasindia.nic.in/) is the agency responsible for framing the security protocols for civil aviation in India. They have a page for [special items](http://www.bcasindia.nic.in/link1travel.html) and a specific link for [photographic film and equipment](http://www.bcasindia.nic.in/passengers/transspec/photOequip.html).

Per this page (emphasis mine)

> Film
>
> The equipment used to screen checked baggage will damage undeveloped
>   film.  Pack your undeveloped film in your carry-on bag.  **High speed
>   and specialty film should be hand inspected at the security
>   checkpoint.  To facilitate hand-inspection, remove your undeveloped
>   film from the canister and pack in a clear plastic bag.**
>
> The screening equipment will not affect digital cameras and electronic
>   image storage cards.

As per the rules, you can request manual inspection of the film at the security checkpoint.